# How to Autofilter then Copy and Paste Visible Cells only

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to basically fill in any blank cells in column **"AM"** with values from column **"AN"** in a worksheet called "Operator" by assigning a shape to a macro with the following code. **Please NOTE** that the cells in An have an equation in them ,so I only want to copy the values.

```
Sub PendingChanges()

Range("AM1:AM10").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

        Worksheets("Operator").Range("AM1:AM10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Worksheets("Operator").Range("AN1:AN10").Value

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1

End Sub
```

I know that there is a "SpecialCells" method that displays visible cells only (so after autofiltering, it would display the blanks for me) but I'm not sure how to include it into my code!
The following screenshot is how the sheet will initially look: (in this example the cell values of **AN3** and **AN5** will paste into **AM3** and **AM5** respectively:

[image]

My code autofilters column **"AN"** for any blank cells, then tries to copy cells in **AN** and pastes the visible cells values into cells in **AM**
The result should be the following:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by using a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to filter here; you can just use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, and then `Offset` on the result to refer to the same rows, but in column "AN".

```
Sub PendingChanges()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim blankCells as Range
    Set blankCells = Worksheets("Operator").Range("AM1:AM10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not blankCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng as Range
        For Each rng in blankCells.Areas
            rng.Value = rng.Offset(,1).Value
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Some notes:

- The `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` are needed since a `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` call will fail if there are no blanks. They temporarily disable and then re-enable error handling.
- [`Areas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas) are each distinct area of a non-contiguous range. For example, if `blankCells` refers to `AM2` and `AM4:AM5`, then `AM2` is the first area and `AM4:AM5` is the second.
- You need to loop through the areas because trying to value transfer `.Value = .Value` doesn't work correctly when there is more than one area.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error with ` Set blankCells = Worksheets("Operator").Range("AM1:AM10").SpecialCells((xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Comment: There was an extra parens - I deleted it.

Comment: Edit, for some reason it's only copying the first value (the AN2 cell value of 5) into all the blank cells of AM

Comment: Edit, for some reason it's only copying the first value (the AN2 cell value of 5) into all the blank cells of AM

Comment: No repro. Is the sheet filtered?

Comment: What's repro stand for? and I just took off all the filters, and highlighted AM1-AM10 then clicked filter, and then ran your code

Comment: Reproduce - I can't reproduce that behavior. Don't filter (first part of my answer).

Comment: I see, I cleared and took off all filters from my worksheet (I don't need any to begin with) and it still seems to be only copying the first value (the AN2 cell value of 5) into all the blank cells of AM

Comment: Nvm let me revise, i see what's going on. Value transfer doesn't work here.

Comment: No I didn't, I just made sure to copy and paste it for a third time, and then simply assign the macro to my "button" (the shape) and then ran it

Comment: Ok see the edit, sorry about that. Using value transfer doesn't work as a one-liner when there are multiple areas.

Comment: I just tested it multiple times, it does exactly what I need it to do! Thank you! If you have a chance, could you explain `On Error GoTo 0` and  `For Each rng in blankCells.Areas` just so I can expand my knowledgebase

Comment: Sure I will add some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the filters and then fill the blanks from next column
You may try the below code, it may directly solve your problem.

```
[VBA]
Sub test()
Dim rBlanks As Range

Set rBlanks = Nothing
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Operator")
On Error Resume Next
Set rBlanks = Intersect(.Range("AM:AM"), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rBlanks Is Nothing Then
rBlanks.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
Intersect(.Range("AM:AM"), .UsedRange).Copy
.Range("AM1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
End With

End Sub
[/VBA]
```

Comment: It's copying "0" from cells "AM6, AM8 and AM10:AM121"